# How can I fix this to apply CSS?

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  font-family: arial;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.thumbail {
  height: 600px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Services - Salazar's Stickers</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='./style.css'>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Salazar's Stickers</h1>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="./home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="./services.html">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="./contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>


  <h2>Personalized Name Stickers</h2>
  <p>
    These stickers can be customized with your name or initials, making it easy to add a personal touch to your belongings.
  </p> <br>
  <img src="./nameStickers.png" class='thumbnail' alt="Personalized Name Stickers">


  <h2>Decorative Sticker Packs</h2>
  <p>
    Our decorative sticker packs include a variety of designs, perfect for adding a touch of creativity to your notebook, phone case, or any other item.
  </p> <br>
  <img src="./decStickers.jpg" class='thumbnail' alt="Decorative Stickers">


  <h2>Vinyl Wall Decals</h2>
  <p>
    Our vinyl wall decals are a great way to decorate your living space. They are easy to apply, remove, and won't damage your walls, making it the perfect solution for apartment dwellers or those who prefer not to make permanent changes to their walls.
  </p>
  <img src="./vinylWallDecal.jpg" class='thumbnail' alt="Vinyl Wall Decals">

  <div class='content'> </div>
  <footer>&copy; Salazar's Stickers 2023 </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

It was working initially, but now, any changes that I implement do not seem to work?
I can't change the color or the text-alignment.
The thumbnail class doesn't seem to be working either.
I'm new to CSS and HTML, so I'm probably sure that this is some simple mistake, but I searched the web and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: It's not clear from the question what, exactly, isn't working -- is _all_ the CSS having no effect?  If so, you've probably broken the link to the css file (did you rearrange files? rename things? have you checked the capitalization?).  If some of the CSS is working but some is not, please be more explicit about what isn't working the way you expect it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, but your css has `.thumbail`, and your html classes have `thumbnail`. You are missing the letter `n`.